# From the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ two numbers are chosen uniformly, with replacement. Find the probability that the product of the numbers is even.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The answer is given, just the reasoning is unclear. Result: $${2\over n}\left[{n\over 2}\right]-\left({\left\lfloor{n \over 2}\right\rfloor\over n}\right)^2,\text{ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the whole part of a number}.$$

The second part of the question is: The probability that the sum of the squares of the numbers is even: again the answer: $$1-{2\over n}\left\lfloor{n\over 2}\right\rfloor+{2\over n^2}\left\lfloor{n \over 2}\right\rfloor^2, \text{where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the whole part of the number}.$$

Comment: "the numbers are chosen at random, uniformly, with replacement" is how I would phrase it

Comment: Hint: consider the probability that the product is odd

Comment: I'm aware of that in some sense i don't understand the reasoning behind this calculation..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First Problem**

There are $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor$ odd numbers in $1\dots n$, so the probability that each number chosen is odd is
$$
\frac1n\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor
$$
Therefore, the probability that the product is even is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A000]{1-\frac1{n^2}\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor^2}
$$

---

There are $n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$ odd numbers in $1\dots n$, so the probability that each number chosen is odd is
$$
\frac1n\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\right)
$$
Therefore, the probability that the product is even is
$$
1-\left(1-\frac1n\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\right)^2=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A000]{\frac2n\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor-\frac1{n^2}\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor^2}
$$

---

**Second Problem**

There are $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor$ odd numbers and $n-\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor$ even numbers in $1\dots n$. Therefore, the number of even-odd draws or odd-even draws is $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor\right)$. Therefore, the probability of an even sum is
$$
1-\frac2{n^2}\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor\right)
=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A000]{1-\frac2n\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor+\frac2{n^2}\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor^2}
$$

---

There are $n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$ odd numbers and $\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$ even numbers in $1\dots n$. Therefore, the number of even-odd draws or odd-even draws is $\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\right)$. Therefore, the probability of an even sum is
$$
1-\frac2{n^2}\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\left(n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor\right)
=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A000]{1-\frac2n\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor+\frac2{n^2}\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor^2}
$$

Comment: what is a floor function?

Comment: That is the $[x]$ that you're using. It is usually written $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and called the floor function.

Comment: not quite 1 is written as 2/n$[n/2]$

Comment: Have you checked to see if they are the same when you plug in numbers?

Comment: Yes, very well same answer, now i just have to figure out why the probability that each number chosen will be odd is... Let me think..

Comment: There are $\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor$ odd numbers from $1\dots n$

Comment: Thanks a bunch, i'll give the second question a thought tomorrow as its late where i am unless you have instant feedback on that too?

Comment: No, but I have figured out how they got that formula :-) I will try the other after dinner.

Answer (score 4):

Probability that you are looking for is equal to $1 -$ probability of product being odd.

Product is odd if both numbers are odd.

Probability of a number being odd is $1 - \dfrac{[\frac{n}{2}]}{n}$.

Probability of both being odd is $\left(1 - \dfrac{[\frac{n}{2}]}{n}\right)^2$.

Square it and you get the probability for odd product to be: $1 - 2\dfrac{[\frac{n}{2}]}{n} + \left(\dfrac{[\frac{n}{2}]}{n}\right)^2$

Even  product is, to remind you: $1 -$ prob. of odd

Therefore $1 - \left(1 - \dfrac{2[n/2]}{n} + \left(\dfrac{[n/2]}{n}\right)^2\right)$

Result: $2\dfrac{[\frac{n}{2}]}{n} - \left(\dfrac{[\frac{n}{2}]}{n}\right)^2$

Comment: Great begining for you, keep this up..

Comment: Second one is trivial. Sum of squares is even only if both numers are even or both are odd. Similar to upper calc just with a bit more writting ;-)